# Share session between two rails 4 application with different subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, single-sign-on

I have two rails 4 application running on shared parent domain `example.com`(`pdf.example.com` and `studio.example.com`). The applications are deployed on AWS and storing session in shared Memcached.

On a page of `studio.example.com`, a page of `pdf.example.com` is loaded in `iframe` which covers the entire visible area. Now when user interacts with iframe content, session created in `studio.example.com` should reset in a sense that timeout should not happen in `studio.example.com` while sitting in pdf.example.com` pages.

The `studio.example.com` application uses devise for authentication.

Here is the configuration used to store session in memcached in `studio.example.com`

**config/initializers/session_store.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.session_store ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore, :expire_after => 30.minutes
```

**config/environments/production.rb**
**config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

There are many resources out there(few listed below) addressing this scenario but all of them are using `CookieStore`. What sort of configuration would be different for `CacheStore`?

1. http://dev.mikamai.com/post/75476602797/sharing-session-between-your-rails-4x-app-and
2. http://excid3.com/blog/sharing-a-devise-user-session-across-subdomains-with-rails-3/
3. https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-share-a-session-between-sinatra-and-rails

**EDIT**
Exact scenario was discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-devise/YD70YLFOyzs) earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution suggested in http://dev.mikamai.com/post/75476602797/sharing-session-between-your-rails-4x-app-and worked.

In both applications do following

1. Set same `secret_key_base` in both applications
2. Configure same key and domain in `session_store.rb`
   `Rails.application.config.session_store ActionDispatch::Session::CacheStore, :expire_after => 30.minutes, key: '_common_key', domain: ".example.com"`
3. Enable caching with dalli in `production.rb`   `Dalli::ElastiCache.new('tripartite.q1ssrz.cfg.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:11211)
   config.cache_store = :dalli_store, elasticache.servers`

Comment: this method work on two different domain for example i want share x.com session storage to y.com, can I do it ?